# Blueimp jQuery File Upload - how to change upload directory

Tags: file-upload, blueimp

how can i change the upload directory?

i want to change the file upload directory dynamically

f.g : for each user,upload files to her/his folder

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can store the directory in a `$_SESSION` variable or in a `$_COOKIE` , and then get the saved value in the file /php/index.php

```
$uplDir = $_SESSION["uploadDirectory"].'/;

$option = array(
    /* some options */
    'upload_dir' => $uplDir,

    /* .... */
);
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($option);
```

ps. remember the `session_start();` at the beginning

Comment: I am sure it would be better to store it in session. Session can not be manipulated on the client side, so one can not change the path to something dangerous.

Answer (score 4):

You can send that via parameters in the form data in js file

```
 <script>
    $(function () {
     $('#fileupload').fileupload({
     dataType: 'json',
     formData: [{ name: 'custom_dir', value: '/save/file/here/' }],
     done: function (e, data) {
     $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
     $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
     });
     }
     });
    });
 </script>
   //=========================
```

while in the upload handler definition

```
    require('UploadHandler.php');
    $custom_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['custom_dir'];
    $upload_handler = new UploadHandler(array('upload_dir' => $custom_dir));
```

Comment: Very nice, exactly what I was looking for!